# How would I go about creating a highlighted grid radius in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm sure you're asking what "highlighted grid radius means" so first let me explain what I am doing. I am creating a Roblox Studio project that involves a grid of grass block tiles as a map. When you click a tile with a selecting building then it makes that building. However, I would like a build radius as you build. For example you cant go, say, 30 grass blocks away from the closest building. I'm setting the default limit as 2 blocks for each building.

In case you are still confused here is a visual aid:

[Example of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCodX.jpg)

The highlighted blocks represent tiles that you can build on while the unhighlighted, obviously, represent blocks that you cannot build on. And yes, I know, in this example the build radius is one block unlike my previous statement. I am just eager to figure this out so I didn't make it any larger.

Now normally I wouldn't even use stack overflow because I would just try to figure it out myself, but I really am stumped. Normally I would have sort of an idea of where to start or how I should approach this and execute the idea. But I just don't know what to do, please help.

EDIT: (specifying issue further) I am unsure of how to actually find which grass blocks are within the radius. I should be able to give them all a SelectionBox I just need a way of finding the ones within the radius.

Comment: Perhaps using [Highlights](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Highlight) or [SurfaceSelections](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/SurfaceSelection) on transparent Parts is a good place to start.

Comment: @Kylaaa I am actually using SelectionBox to highlight the edges of the grass block that is available to build on. But I am not sure how to actually determine which blocks should be selected.